# Array variable is not print out of while loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am initialize a array variable out of while loop and issue is that when this array variable is print out of the while loop then array is not show and when this array variable is print within the loop then array is show.

```
<?php 
  $all_rollno="";
  //Get Current Session
  $Res_Sess = mysql_query("SELECT sessionid from tbl_session where status=1 ORDER BY sessionid desc limit 1");
  $Row_Sess = mysql_fetch_array($Res_Sess);
  $Session = $Row_Sess[0];

 //Get Batch
 $Res_Bat = mysql_query("SELECT batchid,batchname,code FROM tbl_batch where status=1 and batchid!=12 ORDER BY batchid asc");

 while($Row_Bat = mysql_fetch_array($Res_Bat)){
     $Batch = $Row_Bat['batchid'];
     $Bat_Code = $Row_Bat['code'];

     //Present - Attendance
     $Patt4 = mysql_query("select count(id),rollno from tbl_attendance where batchid = '$Batch' and sessionid = '$Session' and attend = 1 GROUP by rollno");

     $arraytpresent="";
     $array_rollno="";
     $ipresent=0;
     while($Row_P4 = mysql_fetch_array($Patt4)){
        $arraytpresent[$ipresent] = round(($Row_P4[0]/$maxValue*100),0);
        $array_rollno[$ipresent] = $Row_P4[1];
        $ipresent++;
     }
     if(sizeof($all_rollno)>0){
         $all_rollno = array_merge($all_rollno,$array_rollno);
     } else {
         $all_rollno = $array_rollno;
    }
    //print_r($all_rollno);
}
print_r($all_rollno);
```

Comment: You should debug inside your while loop and check why your variable is not filled :)

Comment: Yikes! You should not be using those old deprecated `mysql_` calls.  Mission #1: Avoid executing queries in a loop.

Comment: You init `all_rollno` as empty string, why? why not as empty array? Same goes for `$array_rollno`...

Comment: just at the top of your PHP code declare variable $all_rollno =[]; this will make the variable global then you don;t need to worry about all those loops; of you open error debugging of PHP you will get undefine offset all_rolllno notice error. this is because you have declare it as string and using it as an array...

Comment: Can you explain the problem a bit more clear and tell us what you've tried to debug it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the below code I have done 4 changes:

```
<?php
  $all_rollno=array(); // 1. changed it to array

  // get the session
  $Res_Sess = mysql_query("SELECT sessionid from tbl_session where status=1 ORDER BY sessionid desc limit 1");
  $Row_Sess = mysql_fetch_array($Res_Sess);
  $Session = $Row_Sess[0];

  // get the list of badges
 $Res_Bat = mysql_query("SELECT batchid,batchname,code FROM tbl_batch where status=1 and batchid!=12 ORDER BY batchid asc");

 // loop and get the total attendance
 while($Row_Bat = mysql_fetch_array($Res_Bat)){
     $Batch = $Row_Bat['batchid'];
     $Bat_Code = $Row_Bat['code'];

     $Patt4 = mysql_query("select count(id),rollno from tbl_attendance where batchid = '$Batch' and sessionid = '$Session' and attend = 1 GROUP by rollno");

     $arraytpresent=array(); // 2. changed it to array
     $array_rollno=array(); // 3. changed it to array
     $ipresent=0;
     while($Row_P4 = mysql_fetch_array($Patt4)){
        $arraytpresent[$ipresent] = round(($Row_P4[0]/$maxValue*100),0);
        $array_rollno[$ipresent] = $Row_P4[1];
        $ipresent++;
     }

     // merge the data
     $all_rollno = array_merge($all_rollno,$array_rollno); // 4.Merge with the array no need for the if condition.
}
print_r($all_rollno);
```

Please note that mysql is deprecated so use mysqli/PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$array_rollno` should be defined an empty array instead of string:

```
$array_rollno = [];
```

Comment: I have change it but issue is still same

Answer (score 0):

Just change your first line with this, it will work.

```
$all_rollno=[];
```

`$all_rollno="";` this will initialize variable as a string not as an array so change this line with above syntax.

Comment: I have change it but issue is still same